# Complex nested form rails 3 using nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-forms

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I'm using "nested_form" gem in classic way so I'm able to add "multiple tasks" to a "project" while I'm creating a "project". That's not the problem.

To explain the problem I'm going to use an example. Supose I have two models, "Projects" and "Tasks", where project has many tasks and task belongs to project. But in this case I can create a task without a project (foreign key could be null) and I want to make the association later.

So my idea is, when I create the project I want to associate tasks that already exists, so when i save the project, the foreign key in task should be the id of the project just created

Is that possible??, hope you can help me, thanks